# preg_replace not working after updating to PHP 5.4

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am having problem with preg_replace() I believe after updating my host PHP version from 5.3 to 5.4.

The code was working fine earlier but now having problem:

```
function update_comments($comments)
{
  if (!empty($comments) && is_array($comments)) {
    foreach ($comments as &$comment)
      update_comment(&$comment);
  }

  return $comments;
}

function update_comment($comment) {
$repl = '<a href="#">$0</a>';
$comment['comment'] = preg_replace('~#(\d+)~', $repl, $comment['comment']);
return $comment;
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome @abid, Can you add your current output and your expected output?

Comment: What problem have you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow, Abid!

Can you add your current output and the expected output and perhaps your error message? because I see that you use [call time pass-by-reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) which got removed in 5.4. (`update_comment(&$comment)`).

I tried to run the code and adopted it and I see that it seems to work fine after changing it. Here is an example in **declarative** and **imperative** way of doing it.

```
function update_comments($comments)
{
    if (!empty($comments) && is_array($comments)) {
        foreach ($comments as $idx => $comment) {
            $comments[$idx] = update_comment($comment);
        }
    }

    return $comments;
}
```

and here as declarative example

```
function update_comments($comments)
{
    if (!empty($comments) && is_array($comments)) {
        $comments = array_map(function ($comment) {
            return update_comment($comment);
        }, $comments);
    }

    return $comments;
}
```

Here is an example of how I used your code. You can also tinker around here with the specific PHP version: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10e616237c0c75c8e3520bdf5866040231879cde

```
$comments = update_comments([
    ['comment' => 'This is my #1 comment.'],
    ['comment' => 'This is my #2 comment.']
]);

print_r($comments);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array (
//             [comment] => This is my <a href="#">#1</a> comment.
//         )
// 
//     [1] => Array (
//             [comment] => This is my <a href="#">#2</a> comment.
//         )
// 
// )
```

Let me know if this helps or if your `preg_replace()` issue still exists.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond and help.

What I want to search in the string is any number with "#", like #39 #48, etc. and it should replace it with anchor tag added as described in $repl.

I have tried both your ways, but it didnt add an anchor tag. 

I removed pass variable by reference '(update_comment($comment))' to let it work for now. If I use call time pass-by-reference, the site giving the error: 

The website is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @Abid I added an example how I am using it. Additionally I added a "online fiddle" so you can check it against your specific version. Is the desired output not correct? Can you give me more information about your expectations because to me it looks like it's working fine.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification and support. As I am not the expert in PHP, the `print_r` displayed the values perfectly as it had to, but the comments values on site not replacing the values. I tried few things based on your solution and finally it is done with added `return update_comments($comments);` to another function listing the comments. Thanks so much, I really appreciate your prompt and to-the-point solution. :) Thumbs up!!

Comment: @Abid glad I could help and share some insights :)